# Right now i have c# windows form .exe file, Now how can i deploy that in to raspberry pi windows iot core?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, raspberry-pi3

I have created a voice recognition based c# file and also created as .exe file, Now i have deploy in raspberry pi 3 windows iot core, what should i have to do now?

Comment: You can't run a "winforms" windowed program on anything but Windows.

Comment: raspberry OS is based on LINUX system not a window OS at all.

Comment: i can install windows iot core on that

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the executable (usually in the /bin folder of your project). Then you could simply copy the exe onto a usb drive and paste it to your RPi.

You can find all about Windows IoT  on the official website: [Windows 10 IoT Core](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot)

Comment: Does it run?. it is windows form application

Comment: It depends on your implementation. You need to make sure that you have all the dependencies installed. Once you made sure you have that, it should work. Easiest to find out is to test it.

Comment: what are all the dependencies?

Comment: This depends on what your program. The .NET Framework might be one since you're programming in C#